# Portmanteau statistic explanation

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, multivariate-analysis, autocorrelation, vector-autoregression

I am trying to test the autocorrelation of a VAR model using the Portmanteau statistic. I am using the R function `serial.test()`.

I would like to fully understand how this test works. Can someone explain clearly how the statistic is calculated?
$$
Q_h = T\sum_{j=1}^h tr\Big(\hat C_j'\hat C_0^{-1}\hat C_j\hat C_0^{-1}\Big)
$$

Comment: Which of the symbols in the formula do you understand now?

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but I understood that: T - number of observations, C - sum of the multiplication of residuals vectors of the model divided by T, tr() is a trace of the matrix and h is a lag? It is highly possible that I confused everything right now

Comment: The test is a multivariate generalization to VARs of the Ljung/Box statistic (e.g., https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/188344/ljung-box-test-chi-square-distribution). Maybe reading up on this more easy univariate special case helps to buil d intuition?